# How to create a mock mongo client for unit testing?

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, go

I am new to Golang, trying to figure out how to create a mock mongo client for unit testing. I am able to create a mock mongo collection using go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest,

```
mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

collection := mt.Coll
```

However, for creating a client, using `mt.Client` or `mt.Coll.Database().Client()` don't work - getting nil client in result.

Is there anything that I am missing here possibly - kindly guide, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mt.Coll and mt.Client inside the mt.Run()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).